# why am i not getting css and js files in my dynamic web project i tried many ways as mentioned on stack overflow but its not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, eclipse, tomcat

> My Folder structure is my Folder structure is and in one of the html pages i am adding scripts and link as below

```
 WebContent
   |-css(folder containing all css files)
   |-js(folder containing all css files)
   |-html pages(pages are stored directly under webcontent)

<script src="/BoardUI/WebContent/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="/BoardUI/WebContent/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/BoardUI/WebContent/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/BoardUI/WebContent/js/Operations.js"></script>
<link href="/BoardUI/WebContent/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/BoardUI/WebContent/css/business-casual.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `/WebContent` from your urls

`<script src="/BoardUI/js/services.js"></script>`

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I don't know why it has to work this way.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative path like this. I believe main html file also be inside html folder.

```
<script src="../js/services.js"></script>
```

Comment: this one didn't work that's why i posted question answer given by Eric Guan worked for me